# Can an incident photon interact with/be affected by a magneto-static field?

Tags: optics, magnetic-fields, photons

A photon traversing through a magnetized material has it's polarization rotated. This is called the Faraday Effect and is quite heavily studied.
But can an incident photon, like the one created by electron-positron annihilation (0.5 MeV) interact with a strong magneto-static field? (like the one found in MRI machines or even stronger, experimental machines)

I have searched here for some answers and read that a photon's path may be bent when travelling under a super-strong magnetic field (i'm talking Pulsar level strong), but are there any milder, weaker interactions happening in a lab-feasible field?

Comment: I find this a bit confusing. The reason for the Faraday effect has to do with the way the medium reacts and allows light propagation through it, not just because of the magnetic field. So vacuum, afaik, displays no Faraday effect. Of course that I am talking about low-fields, not fields that can interfere with the quantum nature of vacuum. Although it is said as the sign of the effect for electrons and positrons is different, they cancel each other out in electron-positron pair production, so I guess its even hard for vacuum to display the faraday effect for high-field strengths

Comment: and the faraday effect relates to polarization, not deflection

Answer (score 1):

As [seen here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production#Cross_section) photons can pair produce electorn positron in the static electric field of the nucleus

[image: pair]

Since electric and magnetic fields are symmetric  there is no reason an equivalent diagram cannot exist for a static magnetic field. A complicated paper [here.](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0701119)